# Condensing a mercurial repository - recommanded way?

Tags: mercurial, revision-history

Let's say I have a repository 'Main', and Max and co work on a clone each. Max has some local commits ('f'&'g') that are not yet pushed to 'Main'. This is how it looks now (pipes being pushs/pulls):

```
A--B1--B2--C--D1--D2--D3--E (Main)
|          |  |           |
A--B1--B2--C--D1--D2--D3--E--f--g (Max)
```

'B1' and 'B2' as well as 'D1', 'D2' and 'D3' are changes that only make sense together. We would like to combine 'B1' and 'B2' to a single changeset 'B' and combine 'D1', 'D2' and 'D3' to a single changeset 'D'. The new structure should look like this:

```
A--B--C--D--E (Main)
|     |     |
A--B--C--D--E--f--g (Max)
```

My (main) question is: What is the reccommended way of doing this?

---

Now let's make things worse:
We have a branch that was merged within the change-sets that we want to collapse. It would look like this:

```
A--B1--B2--C--D1--D2------D4--E (Main)
|          |  \-------D3-/    |
|          |                  |
A--B1--B2--C--D1--D2------D4--E--f--g (Max)
              \-------D3-/
```

The new history should look like this:

```
A--B--C--D--E (Main)
|     |     |
A--B--C--D--E--f--g (Max)
```

How would you do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much effort you want to put into this. While I don't know a solution within Mercurial itself (I only know history editing functions which can't cope with merges), Git does have the functionality you need:

If I would **really** have to do such an operation, I would

- Try to convince the management that this is not worth it
- Try harder to convince the management that this is not worth it
- Make a backup! The following steps involve destructive operations, so consider this as not optional. *You have been warned*.
- exort the repo with hg-git into a git repository
- export the complete (git) history into a fast-import-stream with `git fastexport --no-data --all > history.fi`
- Create a Pseudohistory by editing `history.fi`, dropping your unwanted revisions
- import the adjusted history into the git repo with ``git fast-import -f < history.fi`
- check extensively if the newly created history is in fact the way you want it to have
- clone `Max` into a local work repository
- Remove successors of commmit `A` in the local work repository
- pull your updated history back from git (again with `hg-git`) into the local work repository
- check, if the Mercurial history matches your expectation (diffs of commits between the new and old repos, metadata (time stamps, committer names, ...)
- Remove successors of commmit `A` in **every** repo (Main, Max and **every** developer clone)
- `hg push -r E Main` the partial history back to `Main` out of the work repository
- `hg push -r g Max` the complete history back to `Max` out of the work repository

Comment: Thanks. Managed to convince management :-) But I'll keep that in mind. It seems to be a sound solution.